# Block access from IP address in Apache2

Tags: apache, security

- I have an apache2 server, serving a website from the following directory `/var/www/`
- I'm trying restrict this website to all but 2 ip addresses
- I've put the code below in the **security** file located on my linux 
  server directory:

***etc/apache2/conf.d/security***

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Order allow,deny
#Allow from IPADDRESS1
Allow from IPADRESS2
</Directory>
```

1) Why can I access the website from IPADDRESS1 when it's commented out?

2) Is this the section of the [apache2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html) that deals with this?

Comment: Please, Please can someone help me understand what can I do to this post to improve it; and get rid of its negative vote? I've rewritten it twice, but am a loss to understand why what is wrong with it. Thanks.

Comment: How can I improve this question when I know the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify to deny all other connections. I.E:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Order allow,deny
#Allow from 192.168.1.4
Allow from 149.254
Deny from all
</Directory>
```